# CSS to fill screen 50% 50% vertically

Tags: html, css

[image]

What's the proper CSS to achieve this for most browsers?

- 2 Divs - 50% and 50% vertically fill the entire screen.
- Each div has 50% and 50% horizontally to fill 1600px width.

```
<!-- TOP 50% -->
<div class="top">
   <div class="left">img</div>
   <div class="right">txt</div>
</div>

<!-- BOT 50% -->
<div class="bot">
   <div class="left">text</div>
   <div class="right">img</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My answer here is relevant: [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/1317805).

Comment: Sort of like this? http://www.flynn1179.net/xml (at least for the left/right split)

Comment: well, sort of, but vertically, the 2 divs stacked on top of each other,

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you can simply substitute width/left/right  for height/top/bottom.

Comment: Thanks James for pointing this out!

Comment: I've updated the post, - view picture.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. This is asking about a 2x2 grid, and post linked is simply asking about making a div 100% height. It uses similar code, but the end result isn't the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Goal:

You want a 2 x 2 grid of boxes. Each box is to be 50% of the window in height and width. This is actually much easier than you'd think. You don't need `.left` or `.right`, you don't need `.top` `.bot`. All you need is a single class called `.row`.

EDIT: You mentioned in comments that you want the width fixed at `1600px;` We just need to add `width` to `body`.

## Code

#### HTML:

```
<!-- TOP 50% -->
<div class="row">
   <div>img</div>
   <div>txt</div>
</div>

<!-- BOT 50% -->
<div class="row">
   <div>text</div>
   <div>img</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    width:1600px;
}

.row {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
.row div {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

## Screenshot

This is from the example below, but I've added colors to make it easier to see.

Edit: The Fiddle has changed to include width. My screenshot is before the width, to demonstrate. It'll look a lot wider, because of the fixed width.

[image]

## Working Example:

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Why did you hard-coded the height of `body` ?

Comment: I hard coded the height of `body` because the question author wanted the boxes to fill '50%' of the screen. This was 2014, and we didn't have things like `vh` units.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this. I tend to favour this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/YyBW7/

```
.top, .bot {
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -4px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've updated the post, - view picture

Answer (score 0):

I think there were some things missing from Samih's answer. Probably `float`
See if this gets you better results:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6D2B/)

Comment: Not a fan of floats so it was "missing" on purpose :p. To me using floats for something like this is not semantic.

Comment: I've updated the post, - view picture